# How to install Sql server 2008 during installation in InstallShield

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010, installshield-2011

I suppose i can check if some sql server is installed, then i want to install one if no one present.
How this can be done?
Prerequisites are not an option because the user can choose installation type were sql server is not required.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can include sql server installer exe in your project and you can use `LaunchAppAndWait` and initiate the exe along with the required parameters.